# Creating Source Assistant in SSIS Throws Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2008

[image]

Hello Every One ..!!

I am trying to Create Basic ssis package  which read text File and Transfer data to another database but when I am  creating  New **source assistant** In **Data Flow tab** From **SSIS Tool Box** I got Above Error .

As per Error I Understand that there is some permission issue but i don't know How to Figure out from this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your development environment is not installed completely... try to reinstall

Comment: Did you ever faced this Problem ..!! I mean this is only solution for it there is no other way except Re Installation.- @Arockia

Comment: I remember the same thing happened to my colleague and he did re-installation.... I dont know any work around for this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
I noted however, that there are the options "Other Sources" and "Other Destinations".
i.e. maybe no requirement to even use the "Source Assistant" and "Destination Assistant" dialog options at all ... on the SSIS toolbox for the Data Flow.